# Angular 2 upgrade to rc 5 - unmet peer dependencies

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, package.json

I need to upgrade my angular to rc5 to use NgModule.

I have followed [directions from Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html).

I have updated my package.json dependencies to this and then ran npm stall in the terminal:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.12.0",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "jquery": "v3.1.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
```

terminal results:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:the-vegan-repository Ben$ npm install

> the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 postinstall /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository
> typings install

typings WARN deprecated 7/26/2016: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160602141332" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)
typings WARN deprecated 8/7/2016: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160621231320" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)

├── core-js (global)
├── jasmine (global)
└── node (global)

npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I have tried the other option suggested by Angular 2:

```
npm install @angular/{core,common,compiler,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic} --save
```

results:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:the-vegan-repository Ben$ npm install @angular/{core,common,compiler,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic} --save
the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.5
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0

npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

No matter what I do to upgrade, I get the same unmet peer dependencies errors.

To fix that I have tried:

npm install @angular

result:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:the-vegan-repository Ben$ npm install @angular
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository/@angular
npm ERR! Darwin 15.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@angular"
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! path /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository/@angular
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository/@angular'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository/npm-debug.log
```

npm install @angular/common

result:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:the-vegan-repository Ben$ npm install @angular/common
the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.5
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0

npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

npm install @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5

result:

```
Benjamins-MacBook-Pro:the-vegan-repository Ben$ npm install @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 /Users/Ben/Development/the-vegan-repository
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.5
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.5
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY es6-shim@^0.35.0

npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of es6-shim@^0.35.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.14 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.4 but none was installed.
npm WARN EPACKAGEJSON the-vegan-repository@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Note that this is a working angular 2 app so I do seem to have angular 2 installed. How do I meet my peer dependencies so that I can upgrade to angular2 rc5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you are getting this error is because you are using `"angular2-google-maps": "^0.12.0"` along with angular2. now `"angular2-google-maps"` is peer dependent on `angular 2.0.0-rc.2` version that's what the error states :

`npm WARN EPEERINVALID angular2-google-maps@0.12.0 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.2 but none was installed.`

this is still an open issue as seen [here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/issues/507).

- I would suggest you to either use `angular 2.0.0-rc.2` till it gets
  resolved.
- Second would be to use `npm i https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/tarball/0.12.0 --save` for installation of google-maps.

hope it helps!

EDIT : they are releasing `0.13.0` version which would be compatible with `rc5` in couple of days. for more info look [here](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular2-google-maps/milestone/9)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a fresh `npm install`? Definitely would recommend. Also try to clean the cache beforehand to ensure you have no prior conflicts:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm cache clean
npm install
```

Also I'd recommend updating your router to `3.0.0-rc.1`. That's the most recent version.

EDIT: I'd also recommend just deleting your `node_modules` directory and getting a fresh one with the install: `rm -rf node_modules`.

Comment: maybe I would empty the old dependencies out of the package.json before and use the --save flag,..

Comment: ran me into a problem on mac that recovering node_modules :(, don't delete the root node_modules, have done it by mistake

Answer (score 0):

if you're still having problems maybe try

```
npm --depth Infinity update
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the same issue which I was also facing-

I just update npm-

```
sudo npm install npm -g
```

My issue got resolved !!!